# How to avoid EADDRINUSE when testing a database with Jest, Graphql and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, graphql, jestjs

I am trying to test a mock database with Jest and Sequelize. I created this helper function, which runs before each test suite:

```
export function handleTestDatabase() {
  beforeAll(() => {
    testDatabase.sequelize.sync().then(() => app.listen(0));
  });
  afterAll(() => testDatabase.sequelize.close());
}
```

I create a connection to my Test Database here and want the Server to listen to any port. The reason I don't give it a specific one, is that I am running into these errors:

```
listen EADDRINUSE :::4001
```

The helper function was written to tackle this issue, but it doesn't work. Is there some way to run all tests sequentially? Because when being run alone, every test suites completes successfully. I already tried this command, but it did not work:

```
jest --runInBand
```

What bothers me even more is that the tests seem to ignore my beforeAll function, because I also get this error:

listen EADDRINUSE :::4001

```
  193 |
  194 | _models2.default.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
> 195 |   return server.listen(PORT, function () {
  196 |     if (process.env.LOGGING) {
  197 |       console.log("Server running on port " + PORT);
  198 |       console.log("Go to http" + secure + "://localhost:" + PORT + "/graphiql for the Interface");

  at dist/index.js:195:17
  at tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
```

This shouldn't happen, because this is from my index.js file, and it shouldn't be reached when testing, because my test command is:

```
"test": "ENVIRONMENT=testing jest --verbose",
```

And I "protect" my app with this clause:

```
if (ENVIRONMENT != "testing") {
  models.sequelize
    .sync()
    .then(() =>
      server.listen(PORT, () => {
        if (process.env.LOGGING) {
          console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
          console.log(
            `Go to http${secure}://localhost:${PORT}/graphiql for the Interface`
          );
        }
      )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      server.close();
    });
}
```

I also tried fixing it by writing a recursive listening function which would reopen the app with another port if there is an error, but that also didn't work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it be using `globalSetup` and creating the server there.

Comment: Thx. I will look into that.